# Is my understanding of kernels correct?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel

System: Application

OS: Scheduler, VMM, IPC, FS Drivers, dispatchers, VFS

The above would be a monolithic kernel. In a monolithic kernel all core
OS functions are separate from user space. Functions such as the FS are
handled completely by the kernel. This leaves the end user/dev open to
write applications that rely solely on the kernel to emulate and process
the functions. The BSD tree, AIX, and HP-UX are good examples of monolithic
kernels.

System: Application

User Mode: Application IPC, Unix Server, Drivers, File Server

OS: Basic IPC, VMM, Scheduling

This is a microkernel. A microkernel is responsible solely for physical
emulation of the machine code. It provides a more secure functionality, but
also allows for better hardware processing. User space is where drivers are
handled, sometimes grating DMA. Also, it can improve computing processing time if the user space is
streamlined for direct machine emulation. JXOS and various nanokernels are
good examples.

System: Application

User Mode: Drivers, Unix Server, Application IPC

OS: Microkernel, Kernel Drivers, IPC, HAL

This is a hybrid kernel. A hybrid kernel is mix between a monolithic kernel
and a microkernel. Software drivers are handled in user mode, but hardware drivers
are handled by the kernel. This allows for a lot of flexibility in design,
as some packages and application functions can run directly against the kernel.
However, this leaves the kernel open to a lot of security vulnerabilities. The
most well-known hybrid kernel is Windows NT.

My architect was testing my knowledge of kernels, and this is what I sent him. He said that I wasn't wrong, I just have a very different approach to it. When interrogated about it, he just told me it was different. How is it different? Does it look different?

Comment: This seems like it would be more appropriate for cs.stackexchange.com. It's not really specific to Unix/Linux, particularly since you mention Windows NT.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic.